# Place cursor where user clicks in a combobox

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I have an editable ComboBox that contains text in it. I'm trying to get it so if the user clicks somewhere on that ComboBox the cursor is placed wherever the user clicked. Currently its behavior is when the user clicks the ComboBox, the entire text is highlighted and the cursor is placed at the end of the text.

I've tried various mousedown events or playing around with selectionstart but that would only be helpful if I wanted to place the cursor at a position like the start of the text or the end of the text. Is this possible with ComboBoxes or am I going to have to restructure to use a different type?

Comment: To improve on the context of the problem, please indicate the framework & version you are using, e.g. .NetCore5, .NetFramework4.8, etc.
Also include code samples, screenshots, etc, or a gist link to a code sample which minimally demonstrates the problem.